# Python "string_escape" vs "unicode_escape"

Tags: python, encoding, escaping, python-2.x, quotes

[According to the docs](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/codecs.html#python-specific-encodings), the builtin string encoding `string_escape`:

> Produce[s] a string that is suitable as string literal in Python source code

...while the `unicode_escape`:

> Produce[s] a string that is suitable as Unicode literal in Python source code

So, they should have roughly the same behaviour. BUT, they appear to treat single quotes differently:

```
>>> print """before '" \0 after""".encode('string-escape')
before \'" \x00 after
>>> print """before '" \0 after""".encode('unicode-escape')
before '" \x00 after
```

The `string_escape` escapes the single quote while the Unicode one does not. Is it safe to assume that I can simply:

```
>>> escaped = my_string.encode('unicode-escape').replace("'", "\\'")
```

...and get the expected behaviour?

**Edit:** Just to be super clear, the expected behavior is getting something suitable as a literal.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

According to my interpretation of the implementation of `unicode-escape` and the unicode `repr` in the CPython 2.6.5 source, yes; the only difference between `repr(unicode_string)` and `unicode_string.encode('unicode-escape')` is the inclusion of wrapping quotes and escaping whichever quote was used.

They are both driven by the same function, `unicodeescape_string`. This function takes a parameter whose sole function is to toggle the addition of the wrapping quotes and escaping of that quote.

Answer (score 15):

Within the range 0 ≤ c < 128, yes the `'` is the only difference for CPython 2.6.

```
>>> set(unichr(c).encode('unicode_escape') for c in range(128)) - set(chr(c).encode('string_escape') for c in range(128))
set(["'"])
```

Outside of this range the two types are not exchangeable.

```
>>> '\x80'.encode('string_escape')
'\\x80'
>>> '\x80'.encode('unicode_escape')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can’t decode byte 0x80 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

>>> u'1'.encode('unicode_escape')
'1'
>>> u'1'.encode('string_escape')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: escape_encode() argument 1 must be str, not unicode
```

On Python 3.x, the `string_escape` encoding no longer exists, since `str` can only store Unicode.

Comment: That is just because '\x80' is not a valid ascii encoded string. Try `u'\x80'.encode('unicode-escape')` and you get `'\\x80'`

Comment: the error is very explicit: UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can’t decode byte 0x80 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128) 

meaning the result of the `ord` function ie:
`ord('\x80')` returns 128
and `range(128)[-1]` is 127
so 128 isnt in there.

Comment: This example is wrong indeed, since `.encode()` shouldn't be called on a string in Python 2.x. And the error is indeed very explicit (if you read it carefully): it is an Unicode *DECODE* error. Why a decode error? Because `.encode()` expects Unicode, and since it is used on a `str`, the string is first decoded using the default encoding, which is 'ascii'. So the error is caused by an implicit decoding using a default encoding due to incorrect usage of the method. It doesn't proof the types are not exchangable outside the range 0..128.

Comment: So the correct answer is: within the full range 0 <= c <= 255, the `'` character is the only character for which the two "encodings" give a different result.