# convert hex ascii mixed string like r'\x74op' to 'top' in python

Tags: python

I want to print out hex string in \xNN.  Is there any quick method to let \xNN convert back to hex string?
I prefer native quick method instead of manual write long function.

eg.

```
$ python
>>> '\x74op'
>>> 'top'

>>> s=r'\x74op'
>>> '\\x74op'

>>> convert(s)  # how to write this function
>>> 'top'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you want `s.decode('string_escape')`.

Comment: More or less same answer :)  +1 to you.

Comment: @wim: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2969044/python-string-escape-vs-unicode-escape