# Python putting r before unicode string variable

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, encoding

For static strings, putting an `r` in front of the string would give the raw string (e.g. `r'some \' string'`). Since it is not possible to put `r` in front of a unicode string variable, what is the minimal approach to dynamically convert a string variable to its raw form? Should I manually substitute all backslashes with double backslashes?

```
str_var = u"some text with escapes e.g. \( \' \)"
raw_str_var = ???
```

Answer (score 3):

If you really need to escape a string, let's say you want to print a newline as `\n`, you can use the [`encode`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode) method with the Python specific [`string_escape`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#python-specific-encodings) encoding:

```
>>> s = "hello\nworld"
>>> e = s.encode("string_escape")
>>> e
"hello\\nworld"
>>> print s
hello
world
>>> print e
hello\nworld
```

You didn't mention anything about unicode, or which Python version you are using, but if you are dealing with unicode strings you should use `unicode_escape` instead.

```
>>> u = u"föö\nbär"
>>> print u
föö
bär
>>> print u.encode('unicode_escape')
f\xf6\xf6\nb\xe4r
```

Your post originally had the regex tag, maybe [`re.escape`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.escape) is what you're actually looking for?

```
>>> re.escape(u"foo\nbar\'baz")
u"foo\\\nbar\\'baz"
```

Not the "double escapes", ie printing the above string yields:

```
foo\
bar\'baz
```

Comment: encode('unicode_escape') escapes only unicode characters and ignores backslashes:
>>> `s = u"fooo \' bar "`

>>> `s.encode('unicode_escape')`

"fooo ' bar "

Comment: No it's because the `'` character doesn't need to be escaped in the first place. In my example the newline is escaped properly.

Comment: `u"fooo \' bar " → u"fooo ' bar "`

Comment: But `unicode_escape`'s behavior seems different than `string_escape` : '>>> `'fooo \' bar'.encode('string_escape')
-> "fooo \\' bar"` ; `>>> u'fooo \' bar'.encode('unicode_escape')
-> "fooo ' bar" `

Comment: Yes there seems to be a subtle difference there. Please see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3001998/98057). If you want full control of the escaping mechanism you probably have to implement it yourself. What's your use case?

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing to convert - the `r` prefix is only significant in source code notation, not for program logic.

As a rule, if you use a single backslash in a normal string, it will automatically be converted to a double backslash if it doesn't start a valid escape sequence:

```
>>> "\n \("
'\n \\('
```

Since it may be difficult to remember all the valid/invalid escape sequences, raw string notation was introduced. But there is no way and no need to convert a string after it has been defined.

In your case, the correct approach would be to use

```
str_var = ur"some text with escapes e.g. \( \' \)"
```

which happens to result in the same string here, but is more explicit.