# The same regular expression doesn't work on my local environment

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I'm trying to match strings like `10\xbd` and my expression is `^[0-9]+\s*\\x.{2}$`. It works well at [pythex](http://pythex.org/?regex=%5E%5B0-9%5D%2B%5Cs*%5C%5Cx.%7B2%7D%24&test_string=10%5Cxbd&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0). But it doesn't work on my local machine.

```
In [223]: pattern = re.compile(r'^[0-9]+\s*\\x.{2}$')

In [224]: print re.match(pattern, "10\xbd")
None
```

I'm using Python 2.7.10. Thank you!

Comment: If your input has a literal ``\``, then it would work: `"10\\xbd"`. See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/YKmUOZ).

Comment: "10\xbd" is a three-byte string: 1, 0, and `\xbd` (which in ISO-8859 and Unicode is the fraction 1/2).

Comment: `\xbd` is a hexadecimal character escape sequence. It will not be parsed as  literally the characters `\xbd` unless your string is prefixed with `r`, like your regex. Where does your string come from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your test:

```
print re.match(pattern, "10\xbd")
```

The "\xbd" is being interpretted a special character.  You need to "escape" it or use a raw string.

Try:

```
print re.match(pattern, r"10\xbd") # the r makes it a raw string
```

or

```
print re.match(pattern, "10\\xbd") # the extra \ 'escapes' the '\' so it is no longer special
```

Comment: Maybe you can add what `r` (raw) does and that he could also escape a single char \\?

Comment: Thank you very much! This answer helped a lot. Since the string comes from  some variable in my case, I need to do `string = string.encode('string-escape')` to convert it. Similarly, in unicode case it can be converted via `string = string.encode('unicode-escape')`. This [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2969044/python-string-escape-vs-unicode-escape) can be referred for details.