# How to replace encode('string_escape') when migrating code from py2 to py3

Tags: python, python-3.x

The 'string_escape' is removed from py3, and I can't find a way to replace the encode('string_escape') when migrating code from py2 to py3. Can someone help me?

My code in py2:

```
a = '["\\\"\\\""]'
print(a.encode('string_escape'))
```

Expected output:

```
["\\"\\""]
```

What should I do in py3?

Comment: You could try `'unicode_escape'` but have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2969044/python-string-escape-vs-unicode-escape

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Jan Wilamowski.
Got the answer.

```
>>> a = '["\\\"\\\""]'
>>> print(a.encode('unicode_escape').decode('utf-8'))
["\\"\\""]
```